# Why does numpy crash instantly upon an array insertion?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management

I've come across some weird behaviour in a project of mine. Specifically, when this code is run:

```
import numpy as np 

coefficientMatrix = np.zeros([12500, 43750])
coefficientMatrix[229, 798] = 1.0942131827
```

my Python process crashes:

[image: error message]

What can be wrong here?

System specs (in case that's relevant here): Windows 7 x64, 8Gb of RAM, Python 2.7 32-bit, numpy 1.9.2.

Comment: `it crashes` Can you post the full trace please?

Comment: @arodriguezdonaire By "it crashes" I mean that windows's "python.exe has stopped working" prompt comes up.

Comment: No problem on my system. Python 2.7 (conda-accelerate) 5 GB Ram, LInux 3.16.0-46 kernel.

Comment: Well you _should_ get a `MemoryError` on 32 bit Python.

Comment: It looks like the array size exceeds the maximum. Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855191/how-big-can-a-python-array-get

Comment: @ali_m You are entirely correct: I installed the 64-bit version and it ran fine :)

Comment: Could you edit your question to mention the `MemoryError` you must be getting?

Comment: @ali_m: I'm not, I just get the "Python.exe has stopped working" dialog with nothing being printed to the terminal. I have to assume this is due to the exception itself occurring inside numpy which then doesn't do anything with it, crashing the whole python executable instead.

Comment: How are you running Python?

Comment: @ali_m: From the command line. Here's a screen showing it: http://i.imgur.com/3uLwPXA.png

Comment: That is a little odd. I assume the lack of a traceback must be due to some Windows-specific issue (I get a `ValueError: array is too big.` with a proper traceback in a 32bit Linux VM). At any rate, I'd highly recommend using an interactive Python interpreter (e.g. [IPython](http://ipython.org/)) for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you would get a `MemoryError` when you assign to an element in coefficientMatrix, rather than when you create the array using `np.zeros`, is that most OSs (including Windows 7) use [lazy memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19755468/1461210).

When you instantiate the array using `np.zeros`, Windows only allocates virtual memory address space rather than physical RAM. However, when you actually try to write to that chunk of memory then the OS will need to find enough physical memory to hold the array. If it fails to do so, you will get a `MemoryError`.

Since your Python process is 32bit, [it can address a maximum of 4GB of memory (and possibly even less)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx#memory_limits). A 12500x43750 array of float64 values will take up 4.375GB of memory, so you simply can't have an array that big using 32bit Python.